# How to raise a warning and still lets "add a line" function work Odoo 15?

Tags: warnings, odoo-15

When click "add a line" button on sale.order.line as example, i want to show a warning message, but then still lets a new line show up, how it that possible?
[image]

In odoo 15 by default, this is not possible, i've try this but not working.

Please help, thanks.

```
@api.onchange('product_id')
    def onchange_product_id(self):
        // my code
        return {
                    'warning': {'title': ('Warning'), 'message': ('my message'), },
                }
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What is happening at the moment and what is it you want? To me it's not clear if at the moment if you have a warning AND a new line (but don't want the new line) or if you only get a warning but also want a new line.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, i mean that by default, when i raise a warning, it won't show a new line, and i want it to raise a warning but also show the new line.

Comment: For me your code works: it shows a message AND adds the selected record. Are you sure you're looking at the right place? You code says 'product_id' but your screenshot seems to show something like 'job_ids'. Or maybe something is going wrong in the `// my code` part?

Comment: @Jasper oh yes thanks you, this code is copy from my company project so i can't copy all of it, also i take a picture from odoo 15 default which is my training odoo site, so the picture and the code is not match.

Comment: @Jasper sir, do you have in mind any idea that can show a warning message but can still lets "add a line" function work as normal? except the code above.

Comment: The easiest way to get help is always to create a 'minimal reproducible example' (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which other users can use to test your approach.